# QGIS plugin WORKS under Windows but NOT under Linux. How to get fîle path properly under Linux?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, linux, qt

I am currently working on a QGIS plugin which depits node to node discreet flows. Let' say adaption of Tobler's Flow Mapper to QGIS.

**Plugin currently tested and working under Windows. But not under Linux or MacOS X.**

As far as I can figure, this is due to a path problem where user chooses the output shapefile location.

Here is what code look likes:

```
def OutputShp(self):
    dlg = FlowMapperDialog()
    fd = QtGui.QFileDialog(dlg)
    global SaveShpName
    global SaveShpDirectory
    SaveShpName = fd.getSaveFileName(None, 'Shapefile(*.shp)', 'Type output shapefile name', '*.shp')
...
...some code...
...

SaveDirectory = os.path.realpath(SaveShpName)
flowpyv07.shapefilemaker(FlowType,str(SaveDirectory), str(SaveShpName),str(InputMatrixName),str(InputNodesName),str(combotext))
```

**When I run it I get the following error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/user/.qgis//python/plugins/FlowMapper/flowmapper.py", line 1346, in run

SaveDirectory = os.path.realpath(SaveShpName)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 358, in realpath
if isabs(filename):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 53, in isabs
return s.startswith('/')

AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Python version:
2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:27:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3]

QGIS version:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, exported

**However, if I enter the "SaveDirectory" path manually in the code such as "/home/user/Documents/" it works like charm. Thus I think I cannot get the path correctly.** Any suggestion is valuable since users regret if it does not work under Linux.

If needed, full source code and plugin is avaliable from the QGIS repo:
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FlowMapper/

Answer (score 3):

The Problem might be that Linux/Mac systems have a different file separator as Windows.
You can print the system specific separator like this

```
from os import path
print path.sep 
> "/"
```

Therefore you have to concatenate your path elements depending on the users system. For instance like this:

```
import os
myhost = os.uname()[0]
if myhost == "Linux":
   directory+os.path.sep+"output.shp"
```

It might be a good idea to print out the `SaveDirectory`-variable on every system to see how it looks like.

Good look with your plugin ;)

Comment: You should really just use `os.path.join` and it will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for valuable help. os.path.realpath(SaveShpName) returns c:\filename.shp while SaveShpName returns c:/filename.shp  Just deleted os.path.realpath and now works under both Linux and Windows