# How to incorporate QGIS custom widgets into plugin?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, widget

Developing a plugin with Qt Designer for QGIS 2.14.1-Essen on Windows 7 and having trouble inserting the `QgsCollapsibleGroupBox` widget. I receive the following error:

> ImportError: No module named qgscollapsiblegroupbox

I put `from qgis.gui import QgsCollapsibleGroupBox` into my *main.py* file but it still doesn't recognise it. Only post I found which mentioned this error is [QGIS custom widgets with python plugins](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-custom-widgets-with-python-plugins-td5173061.html)  but not exactly sure how to install this *qgis_customwidgets.py* file.

I would like this plugin to be transferred to other computers but would like to avoid having to install this file each time (if it is indeed required).

Is there another way to use this type of widget or perhaps a method to save the *qgis_customwidgets.py* into my plugin directory and just call the module?

Comment: Strange, I use the same version of QGIS. Just gave it a try and there is no problem with the QgsCollapsibleGroupBox from Qt Designer. I didn't have to import anything, although I had installed libqgis-customwidgets v.2.14.1 from the repository before.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo - I use Windows 7, I'm not sure how to access this `libqgis-customwidgets v.2.14.1` as most of the information I found online refers using a Linux system.

Comment: Did you already try this solution? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164111/my-plugins-crashes-with-no-module-named-qgsprojectionselectionwidget-in-window

Comment: @GermánCarrillo - Hmm guess I missed that post, thanks! Will take a look :)

Comment: @GermánCarrillo - Yup, that worked! If you post the solution using `qgscollapsiblegroupbox` and perhaps a generic description on how to do this for other widgets, I will accept it? I can also change the title so that it is more generic which hopefully makes it easier to search for.

Comment: I don't think there's a need for a new answer. I'll just mark the post as duplicated to guide new users to the answer. BTW, great that it solves your issue.