# This extension is corrupted : No module named qgscollapsiblegroupbox

Tags: qgis, qt-designer

I'm building a QGIS plugin, and I am making the GUI using Qt Designer.

Whenever I am using one of the "QGIS custom widgets" (in the present case, a QgsCollapsibleGroupBox) in my plugin window, it doesn't work anymore. 
If it's a new plugin and isn't installed yet, it is flagged as corrupted, with the error "No module named qgscollapsiblegroupbox".
And if I modify the GUI of an existing plugin, I got the same error but with a bit more details :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 219, in startPlugin
>       plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
>
> File "C:/Users/eltheo/.qgis2/python/plugins\myplugin__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
>       from .myplugin import myplugin
>
> File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>
> File "C:/Users/eltheo/.qgis2/python/plugins\myplugin\myplugin.py", line 31, in 
>       from list_dockwidget import listDockWidget
>
> File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>
> File "C:/Users/eltheo/.qgis2/python/plugins\myplugin\myplugin_dockwidget.py", line 30, in 
>       os.path.dirname(**file**), 'myplugin_dockwidget_base.ui'))
>
> File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic__init__.py", line 213, in loadUiType
>       exec(code_string.getvalue(), ui_globals)
>
> File "", line 205, in
>
> File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>
> ImportError: No module named qgscollapsiblegroupbox

I had the same problem a couple weeks ago with a QgsFieldComboBox, so I guess the problem lies with all the QGIS custom widgets.

I've looked in the ui_myplugin.py file that it generated when the plugin is compilated, I've found a line at the very end, that seems to be the problem :

> from qgscollapsiblegroupbox import QgsCollapsibleGroupBox

I've try to put that line at the begining of the code with the other import, then to replace it with

> from qgis.gui import QgsCollapsibleGroupBox / from qgis.gui import *

But nothing changes, which is odd for the error should at least be different as there is no more mention of "qgscollapsiblegroupbox" in my files.

Comment: I had the exact same issue a few weeks ago, the answer in this post solved it: [My plugins crashes with “No module named qgsprojectionselectionwidget” in Windows](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164111/my-plugins-crashes-with-no-module-named-qgsprojectionselectionwidget-in-window)

Comment: Did you replace the header of the `QgsCollapsibleGroupBox` class in your _plugin.ui_ file from `<header>qgsmaplayercombobox.h</header>` to `<header>qgis.gui</header>`?

Comment: Just did it. It works like a charm. 
The tiny problem is that I have to do the change again each time I touch my GUI. Qt Designer seems to be erasing this manual modification. But anyways, it does the trick thanks a lot !

Comment: Most welcome! Yes that is correct, which is why I keep my text editor open in my second monitor with the .ui file already loaded ;)