# Fixing headings for QGIS custom widgets in Qt Designer

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qt-designer, qt4

I use custom Qt widgets like [QgsMapLayerComboBox](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerComboBox.html) for my QGIS plugin, laying the whole thing out in Qt Designer. Using those requires fixing headings in .ui file [as described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164119/34438). Unfortunately I have to fix headers every time I save my .ui file.

So the question is: is it possible to make Qt Designer reference qgis.gui headers by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not possible IIRC, it's a bug reported.

I have wrote this script for myself:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    sed -i.bak -e 's|<header>.*</header>|<header>qgis.gui</header>|g' $1
    rm $1.bak
else
    echo "Usage: fix_widgets_ui.sh ui_file.ui"
fi
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks! Do I have to manually launch this every time I save the .ui? p.s. I'm using windows

Comment: Yes, I don't know if you can launch it automatically after each save. The script it's compatible (no GNU or BSD sed specific) with *BSD, linux and OS X. I haven't tested with windows. I think it sould be run with OSGEO4W installation (msys)