# How to use QT QGis custom widget in a plugin?

Tags: qgis, pyqt, qgis-custom-widgets

I am writing a new plugin for QGIS 2.18. I can't find what are the libraries to import in my main code to access widgets such as QgsSpinBox or QgsFileWidget.

Answer (score 6):

To properly use QT QGis custom widgets:
Use imports such as:
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog
from qgis.gui import QgsFileWidget

You must also edit the xx_dialog_base.ui file, to ensure that the widgets are imported from the python module and not from the C libraries (it seems there is a bug in the generation of this .ui file, see [Plugins crashing with "No module named qgsprojectionselectionwidget" in Windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164111/plugins-crashing-with-no-module-named-qgsprojectionselectionwidget-in-windows))

For example:

```
 <customwidget>
   <class>QgsProjectionSelectionWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>qgsprojectionselectionwidget.h</header>
  </customwidget>
```

must be edited as:

```
<customwidget>
   <class>QgsProjectionSelectionWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>qgis.gui</header>
  </customwidget>
```

It seems this edit as to be repeated every time the .ui file is saved by QT designer.